# ERD Review Please

Tags: database-design, erd

I am building a simple database driven web application, but from reading so many books on the subject, I know that if my database is messed up, then my application too, will most likely be messed up.

So I thought I would check with the database design professionals, and get their help in reviewing what I have come up with before proceeding further.

**The Application:**

A website that will make available [ *Event Information* ] to the End User on a Google Map. The events in question are book signing events.

I figured, people read a lot (me one of them), and enjoy reading, and it would be nice to have a website where users can go:

1. Type their post code (zip code), and get all events near them within a set mile radius.
2. Type their favourite author name, and get all his/her events up on the world map.

Nice idea no? I think so anyway :)

Ok, so based on the above, I know that my event table must contain some geographical information, so [I read this](http://bit.ly/WWKnJi). And came up with something like this for my database.

- One Event Can Host Many Book Authors
- One Author Can Only attend One Event at a time.

[ERD Diagram http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/6614/entityrelationshipdiagr.jpg](http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/6614/entityrelationshipdiagr.jpg)

I realise that this is a simple database design, but my application (for now at least) has a really simple aim, and that is to display event information on a Google Map.

I would greatly appreciate any feedback, any pitfalls that I'll face in the future .. etc?

Thank You.

Comment: I don't know what you did to draw your ERD, but your Crow's Foot Noation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crow's_foot_notation#Crow.27s_Foot) is backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, events are not infinite. There's more than one way to represent this in your database: either store an `endTime`, or a `duration`. You could make it optional if you don't want to force it on people, but if the event starts at 4 pm and someone shows up at 11 pm they will be disappointed that they missed the event, and your app was not obviously clear enough that the even ended at 9 pm. You might become the subject of their criticism (whether or not it's rational is a different matter).

You might also want to add a `notes` field that's just some text that anyone can add for special info for the event.

Also, this design does not allow for *One Event Can Host Many Book Authors*. From your diagram, it looks like one event can have exactly one author. You might need a new table such as this:

```
event_authors
-------------
   event_id
   author_id
```

If you make this table have a composite key of `event_id` and `author_id`, it will allow you to have multiple records with the same event and different authors. Of course, you'll have to remove the `author_id` reference from `events`.

As for *One Author Can Only attend One Event at a time.*, this one is a little trickier. Your current schema does not enforce this, but I suppose you could do it in your application. Or you could have an on-insert trigger on `event_authors` that first checks that the time duration of the new event for this author does not overlap any other events for the same author for different events.

Comment: Thanks so much, you have both been very helpful. Excellent point about Duration. If no duration is specified, then the default event run time is 2 hours (handled by code), otherwise it will be whatever is set. Based on both your feedback, I have revised my ERD. It now looks like [this](http://img827.imageshack.us/img827/6614/entityrelationshipdiagr.jpg) Better?

Answer (score 1):

An author is a legal person, same as an attendee, so you could put them in a Party table, and give them a Role, such as "author" or "attendee". A person could play the role of author or attendee or both.

An event occurs at a facility, which is a type of address.

An address is located at a postal/zip code, which is a geographic location. An address is also located in a city (or other geographic area), which is also a geographic location. Cities and postal codes do not have a hierarchical relationship.

If an event can host many authors, then you need an author_event junction table.

[image]

(Note: author_event.event_id should be integer not varchar)